# libGDX drag and drop very slow

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a simple drag and drop drop game, using libgdx and box2d.
On desktop it runs excellent and the movements of the object are flowing, but on android     (Galaxy SIII) is a delay between object and input, so the object is not on the point, the input created.

On desktop, everything ok:

[image]

on Android, delayed:

[image]

the code is very simple, so i dont understand, why it isnt working...

```
Character= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Character.jpg"));
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, 480, 800);

    dx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    public void render(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.128f,0.128f,0.128f,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(Character, object.x, object.y);

        game.batch.end();
        cam.update();



    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
        cam.unproject(touchPos);


        object.x = touchPos.x - 56 / 2;
        object.y=touchPos.y-56/2;


        cam.update();

        return false;
    }
```

Without libGdx the drag and drop movement is working better. But libGdx is necessary for other game features...

anybody got a advice??
Greetings

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt found a solution... But now I think this is, because your Screen has a refresh rate of 60Hz. But when you move your sprite, faster than 60 pixels per seconds, some pixels will be  skipped. And thats why the movement looks "uneven"....

Answer (score 1):

I saw a slight improvement by setting `config.touchSleepTime = 16;` in the Android launcher.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;
        config.touchSleepTime = 16;
        initialize(new SomeGame(), config);
    }
}
```

There is still a noticable lag however hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the FPS?
Its common for the S3 to limit the framerate. 
Make sure all power saving modes are deactivated to achieve 60 FPS.